# PGP - encrypt file passing only file and public key as parameters

Tags: pgp

Security noob here..

We need to encrypt a file before sending it to vendor.
They gave us their public key .asc file.
I want to encrypt using just minimum required parameters as pseudocode below :

> pgp --encrypt "inputFile.txt" --publickey "publicKey.asc"

I have no need to associate the public key with a recipient name or email or import it into 'key-ring', or sign it, or any other such info.

Does my need make logical sense ? Can this be accomplished using PGP ? I found in another [question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25170/what-information-is-leaked-from-an-openpgp-encrypted-file) that GPG has a -R option for hidden recipient. Does PGP have that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What information is leaked from an OpenPGP encrypted file?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25170/what-information-is-leaked-from-an-openpgp-encrypted-file)

Comment: @RobertMennell , is that option available for (Symantec) PGP ? I don't want to use GPG.

Comment: https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH148895.html
I'm not certain, but I found a reference. It looks like the option you MIGHT want is  
`--remove-userid................................................remove a user ID from a key`

As for exactly what you're looking for... sadly it looks like it might not?